# How to apply recommended Dart and Flutter settings in VS Code after installing Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I was setting up VS Code for Flutter and I accidentally gave "No" for the following recommendation

[image: VS Code prompt asking whether to use the recommended VS Code settings for Dart & Flutter]

I tried to find this manually in the settings to enable it, but I wasn't able to find it. How can I change this after the fact?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Steps by Step Solution:

1. Open VS Code
2. Open command palette via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
3. Type `Dart: Use Recommended Settings` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Screenshot of VS Code Command Palette for recommended settings for Dart]

**Note:**
Most probably it will only show when you have a Dart file open
(VS Code does this to prevent cluttering in the command palette)

References:
https://dartcode.org/docs/recommended-settings/